# New-MailContact - Error Message: Couldn't find the Enterprise Organization Container

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm working on a cross-forest migration and I wrote this script to facilitate migrating distribution groups.  I've tested it and it works on a single group.  The script reaches out to the source domain and gets the LegacyExchangeDN and any SMTP addresses on the group.  It then mail-enables the group in the target domain that was migrated with ADMT and adds the Exchange attributes needed for it to function properly.  Finally, the script removes the group from the source domain and creates a mail contact so that users still in that organization can see the group in the GAL.  I added the logic to handle running as a batch job and now I'm getting this error:

[image: Error Message]

None of the Google searches I've found seem to apply to my situation.  Any thoughts why the function that is creating the contact is causing this error?

```
############# FUNCTIONS ###############################
function Get-ExchSessUG{
$exchSessionUG = $null
$exchSessNameUG = 'exchSessionUG'
foreach ($session in Get-PSSession) {
    if (($session.Name -eq $exchSessNameUG) -and ($session.Availability -eq "Available")) {
        $exchSessionUG = $session
    }
}
if ($exchSessionUG -eq $null) {
    $exchSessionUG = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri http://server.domain.com/powershell -Name $exchSessNameUG
}
Import-PSSession -Session $exchSessionUG | Out-Null
return $exchSessionUG
}
function Show-CountdownTimer ($seconds, $reason){
### Number of seconds per 1% block ###
$pctSeconds = $seconds / 100
for ($i = $seconds; $i -gt 0; $i--) {
    Write-Progress -Activity $reason -Status "$i Seconds Left" `
        -PercentComplete ($i/$pctSeconds)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
Write-Progress -Activity $reason -Completed -Status 'Done'
}
function New-MailContactUG ($contact) {  
New-MailContact -Name $contact.Name -DisplayName $contact.DisplayName -OrganizationalUnit $contact.OrganizationalUnit -ExternalEmailAddress $contact.ExternalEmailAddress -Alias $Contact.Alias -DomainController dc.domain.com
}
############# END FUNCTIONS ###########################

$DLs = Get-Content .\dl.group.names.txt
foreach($DL in $DLs){
Get-ExchSessUG
$group = Get-DistributionGroup $DL -DomainController 'dc.domain.com' 
[string]$x500 = 'X500:' + $group.LegacyExchangeDN
$addresses = $addresses = $group.EmailAddresses
###Custom Object###
$contact = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property(@{
    'Name'                 = $group.Alias;
    'DisplayName'          = $group.DisplayName;
    'OrganizationalUnit'   = "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Org,OU=Contact Objects,DC=domain,DC=com";
    'ExternalEmailAddress' = [string]$group.PrimarySMTPAddress;
    'Alias'                = $group.Alias}
)
$group = $group.Name
Remove-DistributionGroup $group -DomainController 'dc.domain.com' -Confirm:$false
New-MailContactUG $contact

Enable-DistributionGroup $group -DomainController 'dc.domain2.local'
Show-CountdownTimer 20 'Waiting for the Distribution Group to replicate...'   
Set-DistributionGroup $group -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false -DomainController 'dc.domain2.local'
Set-DistributionGroup $group -EmailAddresses @{Add=$x500} -DomainController 'dc.domain2.local'

foreach($address in $addresses){
    $fAddress = $address.tolower()
    Set-DistributionGroup $group -emailAddresses @{Add=$fAddress} -DomainController 'dc.domain2.local' | Out-Null
}
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: Well, I will ask the obvious question. Are you positive that the OU exists at the time that you call the function?

Comment: @EBGreen Yes, positive.